# Audit table update trigger does not work using a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table  `tblA`

Which has a trigger defined on it, if any rows are updated it writes the changes to an audit table.

Now if on SQL Server I right click and edit a row directly, I see changes go to the audit table.

If I call a stored procedure to do an update, I do see `tblA` updated but the changed values do not go into the audit table. It seems like the trigger does not get fired at all.

What difference is there between directly editing a table or updating through a stored procedurein term of the trigger being fired.

---

```
Trigger 

USE [dbSuppHousing]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[tblSurvey_trigger]    Script Date: 9/22/2015 2:32:51 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
/* =============================================

 Create date: 08/27/15
 Description:   Trigger to Add audit records to audtSurvey

// =============================================*/
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tblSurvey_trigger] on [dbo].[tblSurvey] 

FOR UPDATE,DELETE

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

Declare   @FieldName varchar(100)
        , @Deleted varchar(4000)
        , @Inserted varchar(4000)
        , @SurveyID numeric
        , @LoginName varchar(100)

Declare  @currentDate datetime = null                                   
SET @currentDate = getdate()

Set @Deleted = ''
Set @Inserted = ''

Select * into #Deleted From Deleted
Select * into #Inserted From Inserted

Create Table #DT ([NameValue] varchar(1000))
Create Table #IT ([NameValue] varchar(1000))

Begin Transaction
    Declare  auSurveyCur cursor for Select Survey_ID from #Deleted Order By Survey_ID
    open auSurveyCur
    fetch next from auSurveyCur into @SurveyID
    while @@fetch_status = 0
        Begin
                Declare  auU cursor 
                for Select [name] from syscolumns where id = object_id('dbo.tblSurvey')
                open auU
                fetch next from auU into @FieldName
                while @@fetch_status = 0
                Begin

                    Insert into #DT execute ('Select ' + @FieldName + ' From #Deleted Where Survey_ID = ' + @SurveyID)
                    Insert into #IT execute ('Select ' + @FieldName + ' From #Inserted Where Survey_ID = ' + @SurveyID)


                                Set @Deleted = (Select isnull(NameValue,'--') From #DT)
                                Set @Inserted = (Select isnull(NameValue,'--') From #IT)
                                If (@Deleted <> @Inserted)
                                Begin
                                    SELECT @LoginName=Login_Name

                                    From Inserted Where Survey_ID=@SurveyID
                                    if @Deleted = '--' begin set @Deleted = null end 
                                    if @Inserted = '--' begin set @Inserted = null end 

                                    --@ForWhat=1 means info is for tbSurvey 
                                    --In future there may be more tables for auditing and we use same
                                    --Stored procedure to insert audit. Each table has its own audit table.



                                    Execute dbo.InsertauInfo @Surv_ID=@SurveyID
                                                            , @auSurveyFieldName=@FieldName
                                                            , @auSurveyChangedFrom=@Deleted
                                                            , @auSurveyChangedTo=@Inserted
                                                            , @auSurveyUpdatedBy=@LoginName
                                                            , @auSurveyUpdateDate=@currentDate
                                                            , @ForWhat=1
                                End
                    Delete From #DT
                    Delete From #IT
                    fetch next from auU into @FieldName
                End
                close auU
                deallocate auU
                fetch next from auSurveyCur into @SurveyID
        END

    close auSurveyCur
    deallocate auSurveyCur
Commit  Transaction
```

---

Code for `InsertauInfo`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertauInfo]
@Surv_ID bigint,
@auSurveyFieldName varchar(100),
@auSurveyChangedFrom varchar(max),
@auSurveyChangedTo varchar(max),
@auSurveyUpdatedBy varchar(100),
@auSurveyUpdateDate datetime,
@ForWhat int

AS

BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON; 
    IF (@ForWhat=1)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO auSurvey
                            ( Survey_ID
                            , auSurveyFieldName
                            , auSurveyChangedFrom
                            , auSurveyChangedTo
                            , auSurveyUpdateDate
                            , auSurveyUpdatedBy
                            )
        VALUES
                            ( @Surv_ID
                            , @auSurveyFieldName
                            , @auSurveyChangedFrom
                            , @auSurveyChangedTo
                            , @auSurveyUpdateDate
                            , @auSurveyUpdatedBy                            
                            )
    END

--ELSE IF (@ForWhat=2)
--      BEGIN
--              INSERT INTO ABC

--      END 
END
```

Example OF stored procedure which does not cause trigger to fire:

OK I'm going crazy but if I Run this very simpple stored procedure directly in DB tirgger gets fired. But if I run from my C# web, Stored procedure will run since tblSurvey gets updated but trigger wont get fired.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUpdateSurveyDataTest]


AS
BEGIN

Update tblSurvey

Set 
[s1FirstName]='YES TRIGGER WORKS  for sureYES'
Where Survey_Id=327


END
```

Comment: please post your  triggers code and tried sp code??

Comment: @Ajmot. Posted in the question

Comment: You should SERIOUSLY reconsider the entire way you are designing this. Cursors, field look-ups, logic issues... what if a value goes from NULL to '--'? Or vice-versa? If you ever had to revert large amounts of changes from a mass update, how are you going to be able to do that with this audit structure?

Comment: In your proc, you insert into "auSurvey" but your trigger is on "tblSurvey", so it wouldn't be triggered.   If this is a typo, please correct it in your question, as it obfuscates the issue.

Comment: This should be set based instead of row by agonizing row. The performance of this is going to be pretty bad. Cursors are horrible for performance and you have them nested inside a trigger. That is like hiding a ticking timebomb in your luggage.

Comment: @ Tab Alleman
Can you please elaborate?  Yes audited  datewill be insert into auSurvey if values of tblSurvey get edited. What is wrong with this?

Comment: @  Sean Lange While I agree, this is legacy code which I'm not allowed to modify.

Comment: @Ghost This is not my design , this is legacy code which i'm not allowed to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of matter was as I mentioned in the question:

Trigger could not be run from App but I was able to fire it directly from a database update.

The problem was application was connecting to DB with its own generic User which did not have Execute permission for Trigger.

To make things more complicated there was no exception at application level.

The fix was to add

```
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
```

To the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger only fires on updates and deletes which is why it fired when you edited the table.  The stored procedure is performing an insert which is undetected by your trigger.  Your trigger should be for **INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE**.

Comment: SP does an Update` not insert Update tblSurvey

Set 
[s1FirstName]='YES TRIGGER WORKS  for sureYES'
Where Survey_Id=327`